# What should be done if Cloud Option is not available in VS 2017 for new project?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-deployment

I downloaded the *Visual Studio 2017* and installed the *Azure Development* from the many options available.
I also downloaded and installed *Service Fabric SDK*.

When I opened the *Visual Studio*, it does not show any *Cloud* option under *Installed* options.

Could anyone help me in this?

[image: Picture]

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVNx1.png)

Comment: I don't think there is a 'Cloud' option. You use Azure SDK in your projects. So, if you can tell us what you are trying to build, and how it will work with Azure, may be we can help better.

Comment: Please check this link --- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVNx1.png, like what am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link clarified things. You probably know this already but you need to rerun visual studio setup, and add the components you want.

To rerun setup...

1. Quit Visual Studio.
2. Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features
3. Select Visual Studio 2017
4. Select Change > and you should get an option to Modify.
5. Here, put a check mark to everything under 'Web Apps' or something similar. You can also go through the list of you will see that Azure is one of them.

If you already tried this, then, I don't know but based on the screen shot above, this is most likely your issue.

Comment: Thanks Jay . It worked . I will reach out to you if I face any issues during development .